# Change of variables to get the Gaussian Integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

The integral is: 
$$ I =\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\alpha x^{2}}ch(\beta x)dx $$

My investigation gives me:
$$ ch(\beta x)=\frac{e^{\beta x}+e^{-\beta x}}{2}$$
$$I= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\alpha x^{2}}(\frac{e^{\beta x}+e^{-\beta x}}{2})dx = \frac{1}{2}(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\alpha x^{2}}e^{\beta x}dx + \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\alpha x^{2}}e^{-\beta x}dx)$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\alpha x^{2}}e^{\beta x}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\alpha x^{2}+\beta x}dx$$ 
I think that [the Gaussian Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianIntegral.html) is the key. But I can't find the right substitution for $ -\alpha x^{2}+\beta x $ and $-\alpha x^{2}-\beta x$. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Compete the square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$-\alpha x^2+\beta x=-\alpha\left(x-\frac\beta{2\alpha}\right)^2+\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}$$

Thus, with $u=x-\frac\beta{2\alpha}$, we get

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\alpha x^2+\beta x}\ dx=e^{\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\alpha u^2}\ du$$

---

For the second integral,

$$-\alpha x^2-\beta x=-\alpha\left(x+\frac\beta{2\alpha}\right)^2+\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}$$